# Using a Macro to reformat a PivotTable at every change

Tags: vba, excel

I have a PivotTable which reformats itself every time a new filter is set, or a field is collapsed/expanded. I have built out a macro which reformats the columns in the way that I want, but I have had to link it to a button that must be clicked after the pivot table change. I would prefer if the macro ran itself upon any change in the pivottable, but my attempts to automate this have either generated an error or no action whatsoever. I have tried using "`Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Sheet)`" as well as "`Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)`" but neither works. Do I have to assign a specific PivotTable number or sheet number into those to get them to work? The current code I have is entered in as follows;

```
Sub FormatPivot()
'
' FormatPivot Macro
'
    Columns("D:H").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 17.56
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    Cells.Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Range("B3").Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Call FormatPivot
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the references to the cells on the pivot sheet, not the active sheet.

```
Sub FormatPivot()
'
' FormatPivot Macro
'

'
    Dim Pivot as Worksheet
    Dim MyRange as Range
    Set Pivot = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("thenameofthesheetwithpivot")
    Set MyRange = Pivot.Columns("D:H")

    MyRange.ColumnWidth = 17.56

    With MyRange.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Call FormatPivot
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is keeping the column widths fixed, you can right click in the pivot table and choose PivotTable Options... and at the bottom, there is a check box for Autofit column widths on update. If you uncheck that, you should be able to set you width to 17.56 and it will stay that way.